# Can you get a handle to a document someone else has open and save an close it using lotuscript?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I have an agent that runs every 5 minutes looking for comment documents that have been open longer than 5 minutes.  I would like to get a handle to the open document, save it and close it.  Is this possible in Notes?

MJ

Comment: No its not possible. No way.

Comment: Agreed. You can't do this with an agent.  You can probably do it with a combination of some bits of LotusScript code that run in the PostOpen and QueryClose events, along with some plugin code that runs on the client. Probably. I'm not sure how advisable it would be, though.

Comment: What's the use case?  Is it to act like an auto-save feature?

Comment: Is this via notes client or web ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the way to do this is with a `NotesTimer` object but you have to do this in the UI, not an agent. Initiate the `NotesTimer` in the `PostOpen` or `PostModeChange` UI events if the document is in edit mode. See the examples in the Domino Designer Help database for guidelines on implementing this solution.